# "Xcode couldn't find any iOS App Developement provisioning profiles matching..". Can I fix this without a real mobile device?

Tags: ios, xcode, flutter, provisioning-profile

After deploying a flutter app on google playstore I am trying to do the same on the apple appstore. Currently trying to configure everything in xcode but I get 2 error messages in xcode:

1. Failed to create provisioning profile. There are no devices registered in your account on the eveloper website
2. No profiles for 'bundle-id' were found

Error 2) shows up when I try to build the "build archive" with `flutter run ipa`

I have an apple developer account and trying this on a macbook pro. However I do not have a real apple iphone. I couldn't fix this with any solutions I tried so far and the only thing that seems to work is plugging in a real device

What else can I try except purchasing an iPhone?

Comment: A provisioning profile is required for private releases, like `Ad Hoc Distribution. Are you sure you are selecting the correct deployment option in Xcode?

Comment: "flutter build ipa" is to create an archive.

Comment: @MarianoZorrilla Following the flutter docs that is something that I have to do to upload the build to app store connect. If I run flutter build ipa I get one error, the second one that I mentioned

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 6):

You have to register atleast one device in developer account for creating the provisioning profile for publish the app on App Store. You do not actually own iPhone you can add the test device UUID or you can ask client for device UUID for testing or you can ask to your friend and colleague to prevent this error.

Comment: Thank you, very wired error that says nothing on what exactly it is